# Should I post, or not post a new question with clarifying information?

Tags: discussion

I recently posted a question:

[User reporting that Push Notification doesn't always show in the notification center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/377573/user-reporting-that-push-notification-doesnt-always-show-in-the-notification-ce)

It was closed with the following notice at the top:

> Closed. This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers.
>       Add details and clarify the problem you’re solving. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question or post a new one.

I posted a new question, with more details and clarity.

It was **also** closed, with the statement from the moderator:

> Please don't repost questions. If your original question needs clarification, edit that question instead so it can be reviewed and reopened.

Yet the modal on the first question said to, "post a new one"

So, should a new question be posted or not, when you need to clarify further, and a question is closed?

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to Meta, things are easier to discuss here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree that the messages you got are conflicting (and it probably doesn't help you if I admit that I was totally unaware of the fact that the close message recommends "edit existing *or* post a new question"). And as far as I know we don't have specific rules on whether to do one or the other. Nevertheless let me share my thoughts on this:

- In general questions which are put on hold should be *edited* based on the feedback received in the comments. This allows everybody to chip in in order to improve the question and makes it easy to understand what's going on. It also makes sure that details which are only visible in the comments are not lost
- Posting a *new* question might be an option if the original question already gathered a lot of downvotes (which usually are difficult to get rid of even if the edited question is well written) or if, based on the feedback received on the original question, the new question goes into a totally different direction (e.g. if the first question was a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and you now ask Y as a new question) or needs to be split into two individual questions

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

There are some question bans about asking -not-so-good- questions in a row which can be lifted only through improving existing questions, instead of deleting/ abandoning them and asking new ones. Though it is dependent on downvotes, which you didn't get many.

read on main meta for more: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Also, asking a new question is preferable if someone is asking too many of the followup questions, which leads to "clarity" or "focus" close votes (though I'd love if they're worded better).